how can I be able to create a local website?
since two days i tried and tried to create a local website by Wordpress in localhost . but i am fail. localhost refused to connect the site.enter image description here
I created a website by wordpress app . I also installed Xampp app and all works I have finished properly but finally i failed to open the site in localhost. i have created 'localhost/batch45' website. I have no proxy settings . I want to create website for educational purpose, my exam is near at hand but I am failure to complete the task.

can you verify if your localhost is working fine?
what do you see when you add only localhost in the browser, also try creating a file test.php and put it under htdocs dir and see if you can run that file

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Without further information, we won't be able to fully understand how to help. However, I would expect simply navigating to localhost in your browser would work.
If not, a few points that may explain your issues:

You may need to set up a virtual host in XAMPP to create a local batch45.local domain. The w3docs site has a simple to follow walkthrough: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/php/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp.html
It could be that you can already browse to batch45.local or batch45.dev domain. Try it, but it may need you to follow step one anyway.
A third option is to try browsing to http://batch45 and see if that works. The AskUbuntu site has some information on doing this from the position of a user getting an error. (see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474135/how-to-run-multiple-web-sites-on-localhost-with-apache)
Finally, if you know the port number of localhost (for example, 8888), you can try localhost:<port-number>/batch45.

In short, and without further information, your solution is to set up virtual hosts in XAMPP to browse to a specific local domain of your choice.
